# flutter How to align text in a row /column

Tags: flutter

I am writing a row of data with space between the item. However, the items on the right side are not aligned properly.

As you can see from image the right elements are aligned to the end

How do I fit it so the "*" are aligned

[image]

Here is my code

```
static pw.Row makeRow(String sk1, String sk2) {
    return pw.Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <pw.Widget>[
        pw.Column(
          children: <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Row(
              children: <pw.Widget>[
                pw.Container(
                  width: 2.0,
                  height: 2.0,
                  decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
                    shape: pw.BoxShape.circle,
                    color: PdfColor.fromInt(Colors.black.value),
                  ),
                ),
                pw.SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                makeTextField(sk1, size: 11.0),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
        if (sk2 != null)
          pw.Column(
            children: <pw.Widget>[
              pw.Row(
                children: <pw.Widget>[
                  pw.Container(
                    width: 2.0,
                    height: 2.0,
                    decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
                      shape: pw.BoxShape.circle,
                      color: PdfColor.fromInt(Colors.black.value),
                    ),
                  ),
                  pw.SizedBox(width: 4.0),
                  makeTextField(sk2, size: 11.0),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

I am looping through a list and calling the method to create a row.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
       children: [
         Column(
         children:[
           Text('Skill 1'),
           Text('Skill 2'),
         ]
         ),
         Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           // If you want to move it to the end just use CrossAxisAlignment.end
         children:[
           Text('Skill 1'),
           Text('Skill 22222'),
         ]
         ),
       ]
      )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

This code will give you following output:
[image: The Output]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
      Text('Skill 12938'),
      Text('Skill 2')
      ]
    ),
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
      Text('Skill 3'),
      Text('Skill 42938')
      ]
    )
  ]
)
```

demo: https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **table** widget instead of columns and rows

Look at

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html